# Не работает discord.js и discord.py

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.py

Не работают библиотеки discord.py и discord.js. Не запускают бота, а если и запускают, то во 1 на 5-10 секунд, во 2 не реагируют на сообщения пользователя. Что делать? Все пробовал: токен регенерировал, переписывал код. Помогите

Код discord.js

```
const discord = require("discord.js")

const bot = new discord.Client( {intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES"]} )

bot.on('messageCreate', async (message ) => {
     if (message.author.bot) {
        return
     }

     if (message.channel === await message.guild.channels.cache.get(0000000000)) {
        await message.channel.send("Hi")
     }
})

bot.on('ready', async () => {
     console.log("Ready!")
})

bot.login("TOKEN")
```

discord.py:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix="!")
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
     await message.channel.send("Hi")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй на сайте дискорд девелопер дать боту доступ на чтение сообщений.
Если не поможет, то включи все разрешения и намерения на сайте дискорд девелопер а в коде добавь:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'], intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Должно помочь.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    #comand mute
    for x in blacklist:
        if (x in message.content.upper()):
            await message.delete()
    if message.content.startswith('привет') or message.content.startswith('Привет'):
        await message.channel.send('Привет!')
    if message.content.startswith('пока') or message.content.startswith('Пока'):
        await message.channel.send('Пока!')
```

Вот код можешь попробовать

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно бот был заблокирован или получил задержку при работе с discord api

Попробуйте добавить это в ваш код и посмотрите, что будет записано в файл `discord.log`

```py
import discord
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='discord.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

И еще, у вас бот должен отправлять сообщение в ответ каждое сообщение, то есть уходить в бесконечный цикл вызовов `on_message`, который прерывается только задержкой от discord api

Comment: Код создал файл discord.log, в котором ничего нету. Что это значит?

Comment: вы просто запустили этот код или добавили к себе?